# Bind data inside ListBox using code-behind in ReactiveUI

Tags: reactiveui

I have WPF listbox:

```
<ListBox Name="FileDownloads" SelectionMode="Extended">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Name="Url" Text="{Binding Url}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I like the ability to bind ListBox by name from code behind using:
`this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.DownloadManager.FileDownloads, v => v.FileDownloads.ItemsSource);` Having binding in code-behind helps with refactoring.

Is there any way to bind Url texbox inside the listbox using code-behind?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any way to bind Url textbox inside the listbox using code-behind?

Not at the moment. You can either use XAML bindings like you're doing now, or you can put your data templates inside UserControls.

A consolation to this somewhat more cumbersome approach, is that if you register your data template UserControls and implement `IViewFor<TViewModel>` on them:

```
Splat.Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(typeof(MyView), typeof(IViewFor<MyViewModel>));
```

Then, you can write the ListBox simply as:

```
<ListBox Name="FileDownloads" SelectionMode="Extended" />
```

This line will automatically wire up a DataTemplate for you:

```
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.DownloadManager.FileDownloads, v => v.FileDownloads.ItemsSource);
```

Comment: Great, Thanks! The only thing I needed to write `Splat.Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => new FileDownloadControl(), typeof(IViewFor<FileDownload>));` not `Splat.Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(typeof(FileDownloadControl), typeof(IViewFor<FileDownload>));`

Comment: I also added a 'Delete' button inside UserControlView and binded it to ReactiveCommand in a UserControlViewModel. When I subscribe to Delete command from UserControlViewModel - it works fine. When I subscribe to Delete command from UserControlView - it is not fired. I used `this.BindCommand(ViewModel, vm => vm.Delete, v => v.Delete);
            ViewModel.Delete.Subscribe(x =>  MessageBox.Show("Click From View"));` and `Delete = ReactiveCommand.Create();
            Delete.Subscribe(x=>MessageBox.Show("Click from ViewModel"));`