# How works IViewFor Bind extension method?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, reactiveui

Simple question, but I dons see solution. Or may be dont understand how Bind method works.
The goal is two way binding between ViewModel and DataContext properties.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Bind(this, v => v.DataContext, v => v.ViewModel);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ViewModel", typeof (string), typeof (MainWindow));

    public string ViewModel
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value); }
    }
```

when I set ViewModel property, I get InvalidCastException "System.String" to "WpfApplication1.MainWindow".

But xaml binding works perfectly.

```
<MainWindow 
   DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}" ...
```

full xaml.cs/xaml code is here http://pastebin.com/iCKeNS7R

Where I wrong ?

**update:**
this code:

`this.WhenAnyValue(v => v.ViewModel).BindTo(this, v => v.DataContext);
this.WhenAnyValue(v => v.DataContext).BindTo(this, v => v.ViewModel);`

also works as expected

**update 2**
Question: Does this.Bind(viewModelParam, ...)  ignore viewModelParam argument ??

example^ http://pastebin.com/e2aPaGNc

I bind to _otherViewModel, but when type text into textBox, ViewModel.StrProp changed, not _otherViewModel.

Does anybody know, how this.Bind work ??

Comment: is this just an example or why you bind the datacontext from your mainwindow to a string?

Comment: yes, it's for example only, I have "normal" viewmodel class of course

Comment: Will: what exackly is wrong? See here (https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples/blob/master/ReactiveUI.Samples.Routing/Views/WelcomeView.xaml.cs) only one diff bettween that code and mine is binding/ Code by link use: this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ViewModel).BindTo(this, x => x.DataContext); I try to use this.Bind(this, v => v.DataContext, v => v.ViewModel); Why their code works, but mine dont ??

Answer (score 74):

`Bind` doesn't work between ViewModel and DataContext because the types don't match (i.e. I could set DataContext to '4' and now it can't assign that to ViewModel).

However, if you are using ReactiveUI bindings, you don't **need** DataContext at all, you should just use RxUI bindings everywhere. Please ignore the other answers on this thread that tell you how to do things the wrong way.

Comment: For the love of god will someone please mod this up and mark as the answer!

Comment: Yes, please, this guy wrote the *** FW !

Comment: >>you don't need DataContext at all, you should just use RxUI bindings everywhere
It's hard to do. For example i should use seperated IViewFor impementations instead datatemplates  ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466260/bind-data-inside-listbox-using-code-behind-in-reactiveui )
On other hand, why this.WhenAnyValue(v => v.DataContext).BindTo(this, v => v.ViewModel works ???

Comment: In case of attached property **DataContext** is needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can just bind the ViewModel via XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="YourNameSpace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ViewModel:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding YourProperty, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource MainViewModel}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

your viewmodel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _yourProperty;
    public string YourProperty
    {
        get { return _yourProperty; }
        set { _yourProperty = value; OnPropertyChanged("YourProperty"); }
    }


    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _yourProperty = "Some string";
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```